# How to connect to mysql database in Linux from VS2010's server explorer

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010, database-connection

I'm trying to add a database connection from Server Explorer of VS2010 to MySql database deployed on Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a connection with a MySQL database, perform the following steps:

Start Visual Studio, and open the Server Explorer window (View, Server Explorer option in the main Visual Studio menu, or Control+W, L keyboard shortcuts).

Right-click the Data Connections node, and choose the Add Connection... menu item.

Add Connection dialog opens. Press the Change button to choose MySQL Database as a data source.

Refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-net-visual-studio-making-a-connection.html